# How can I use form objects with mongoid in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, mongoid4

With Active record I can do the following to get form object.

## Rails 3

```
class TestForm
 extend ActiveModel::Naming
 include ActiveModel::Conversion
 include ActiveModel::Validations

 def persisted?
  false
 end
end
```

## Rails 4

```
class TestForm
 include  ActiveModel::Model
end
```

but how can I acheive the same with Mongoid 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this https://github.com/apotonick/reform

Reform provides the following Mongoid specific features. They're mixed in automatically in a Rails/Mongoid setup.